# How to get the original value of a field that is inside a field collection?

Tags: 7, entities

I can get the entity reference field node id from my field collection like this:

```
function mymodule_node_update($node){

    if ($node->type == 'article'){    

    $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);

        $before = array();

        foreach ($node_wrapper->field_collection_ingredients->value() as $key => $field_collection_wrapper) {

          $before[$key] = $field_collection_wrapper->field_ingredient[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'];

        } 
  }
```

Doing:

```
$before[$key] = $field_collection_wrapper->original->field_ingredient[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'];
```

Causes an error.

---

Basically I have an entity reference, which allows unlimited values, inside the the field collection.

When someone removes a value from the entity reference field, I need to know which value was removed as I need the Node ID to update that node that was removed from the entity reference.

Comment: Did you tried comparing `field_collection_ingredients` field value for `$node->field_collection_ingredients[LANGUAGE_NONE]` and `$node->original->field_collection_ingredients[LANGUAGE_NONE]`, this will give exactly which field collection was removed, you can then try loading that field collection and then load `$fc->field_ingredient[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'];` field value to update Node referenced in `field_ingredient` field.

Comment: @Yogesh this almost worked, except Drupal throws an error when it tried to load the entity reference nid. Seems like once you remove the item, the collection that belongs to that ID gets removed, which causes the error.

Comment: If your node has revision enabled then field collection is not removed, instead archived. If not, then it is removed

Comment: @Yogesh are you saying that I need to use the revision id?

Comment: No, I'm just saying that, if your node does not has revision enabled, the field collection might be removed from database, if you remove from node.

Comment: @Yogesh Ok I see, I enabled revision and it worked, got rid of the error, can you post this as the answer? I'd like to give you rep.

Comment: Glad it worked. Ok sure, will add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try comparing `field_collection_ingredients` field value of `$node->field_collection_ingredients[LANGUAGE_NONE]` and `$node->original->field_collection_ingredients[LANGUAGE_NONE]‌`​, this will give exactly which field collection was removed, you can then try loading that field collection (*see note below*) and then load `$fc->field_ingredient[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id']`; field value to update *Node* referenced in `field_ingredient` field.

***Note:*** If your node does not has revision enabled, the removed field collection will be removed from Drupal database as well, which will cause the error when trying to load the Field Collection Entity. So you might need to enable revision for your main node, to make sure that if field collection is removed from `field_collection_ingredients` field, it will not get removed from Database.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question in the right way field collections create entities. So you can try to use hook_entity_update to track when your field collection entities are updated (i mean when someone deletes values from entity reference field of your field collection) `hook_entity_update($entity, 'field_collection_item')`. 
You also can use `entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $your_field_collection_entity_id)` to get data from field collection entity.